# MAC Address Spoofing causes VM Machine to lose physical connection?

Tags: networking, internet, mac-address

I currently paid for a Network Testing/Python coding course online and one of the first programs we created was a MAC address changer.

When I change the MAC address of my Virtual Machine it cuts out the internet connection and the virtual machine refuses to connect to the internet.

So far the only way I know how to reset the MAC address is to reset the machine.

The course seems to suggest that spoofing a MAC address will not result in internet problems and that the VM Software can handle a MAC address change. Unsure what the issue could be.

In network settings there is the possibility to change the MAC address and a randomizer. I've attached a picture to help understand what I am working with.

[image: MAC Adapter settings in a VM Machine]

Is there a setting that will let me have a dynamic MAC address and so have a MAC address changing program that will work and not disconnect the internet every time?

Posting from the UK.

Comment: Couldn't it just be that your VM software doesn't expect the guest OS to ever change its fake MAC address, and so the VM software isn't handing the new MAC address correctly? Do you know for sure that your VM software supports having the guest OS change the VM's virtual NIC's MAC address?

Comment: I presume the VM software should compensate for a change in MAC as this course told me to download a specific program. It would be a pretty big oversight if the VM software did not recognize MAC changes. When connected to the internet the VM OS sees the connection as a wired connection but when I change the MAC address of the the VM OS disconnects and will not reconnect. Is there something specific I need to be looking for in the VM settings that I might have missed?

Comment: Your expectations make sense, but VM software often _deliberately_ restrict the VM to its "own" MAC address. Yes, check settings.

Comment: I think we're getting closer to an explanation. The guide does not go into why changing a MAC address from the VM own MAC address might cause problems.

This is a pretty big oversight for a paid guide. I am using "Oracle VM VirtualBox" to create my VMs. I've looked in the network settings but there doesn't seem to be any references to MAC addresses specifically. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: It's in the "Network" section of the VM, hidden in an expander. Can't upload a screenshot at this time, but you'll find the MAC address field there. VirtualBox's manual is also fairly extensive and should mention MAC spoofing somewhere.

Comment: There is a specific field for MAC address and a randomizer. I can just randomly reset the MAC address from here but there doesn't seem to be a setting that allows fluid MAC address. I'll try finding the manual!

Comment: have you considered using a bridged connection? you are using NAT now, so the Virtual Network has to map flows from inside to outside and back again through your host PC. Connecting it directly to your home network (thats what bridging does) may work better. just a hunch.